# How can I count how often a specific char appears before other specific char appears for the first time?

Tags: c#, string, char

I have a `string` like `asdafahxlkax`.

How can I count that `a` appears 3 times before the first `x` appears?

Thanks.

Comment: Use you imagination and try some things with String.Substring() and String.IndexOf()

Comment: `var result = "asdafahxlkax".TakeWhile(z => z != 'x').Count(z => z == 'a');`

Comment: Loop thru one by one character, increment the count when `a` found. Exit the loop when `x` found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = "asdafahxlkax"; 
char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();

int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    if(chars[i] == 'a')
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else if(chars[i] == 'x')
    {
        if(counter == 3)
        {
            // success
        }
        else
        {
            // fail
        }
    }
}
```

You need to define if you want this to fail when x is contained 0 times. But in general this is a simple approach.

Comment: Just a tip:  There is no need for the call to `ToCharArray` or the `chars` variable.  The `string` class implements `IEnumerable<char>` so you can just loop through the characters of the string directly.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public int CountBeforeChar(char toCount, char beforeChar, string testString)
{
  // Handle situation where we cannot find beforeChar in testString
  var idx = testString.IndexOf(beforeChar);
  idx = idx == -1 ? testString.Length - 1 : idx;
  return testString
    // Take substring until first occurence of "beforeChar"
    .Substring(0, idx)
    // Count all occurences of desired character in that substring
    .Count(ch => ch == toCount);
}
```

Comment: I like this. Not sure if  `5 times 'a' before x` would also be valid, or what should happen when x isn't part of the string, but a etc...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be splitting the string by the other char and count the occurrences of the target char in first part:

```
string str = "asdafahxlkax";

int count = 0;

if (str.Contains('x'))
    count = str.Split('x').First().Count(c => c == 'a');
else
    count = str.Count(c => c == 'a');
```

Update: 
More clean and effecient solution would be just using the `TakeWhile` to get part of string before 'x' (if exists, or it will get the entire string) and count the occurrences of target char (credit: @mjwills):

```
int count = str.TakeWhile(c => c != 'x').Count(c => c == 'a');
```

Comment: This could likely be simplified to `var count = str.Split('x').First().Count(c => c == 'a');` Note - it will almost certainly be slower than the earlier `TakeWhile` solution (since you are iterating the string multiple times, allocating new strings etc).

Comment: @mjwills there could be chances of absence of _'x'_ in the string so I tried to make the solution passed all test cases, and I agree `TakeWhile` would be more clean and efficient option.